# "Not all controlpaths return a value" / "control may reach end of non void function" when validating with while loop?

Tags: c++, string, loops, controls

I'm trying to validate inputs that aren't the integers 1, 2, or 3. I'm using a do/while loop but it doesn't work and just keeps repeating. What's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string decisionThing(int);


int main()
{
    int response;
    cout << "Enter the section you are in in\n";
    cin >> response;

    do
    {
        cout << "Are you in section 1, 2, or 3?";
        cin >> response;


    } while (response != 1 || response != 2 || response != 3);

    cout << decisionThing(response) << "\n";

}

string decisionThing(int response)
{
    string date;

    switch (response)
    {
        case 1:
            date = "The test will be held on the 5th.\n";
            return date;
            break;
        case 2:
            date = "The test will be held on the 6th.\n";
            return date;
            break;
        case 3:
            date = "The test will be held on the 9th.\n";
            return date;
            break;
    }
}
```

It's supposed to execute the do/while loop is true (the user enters some input like `155` or `"zebras"`).

Comment: Although you only ever call `decisionThing` with `1` `2` or `3`, what if it were called with another value, what would it return?

Comment: As @Tas pointed out, you need to handle the case when the input isn't 1, 2 or 3. I understand that in practice, it might be impossible for such thing to happen, but in the eyes of compiler, this method could be given an input that's neither of the cases covered by your switch and in that case, it's unclear what should happen. I'd add a `default` case or return an empty string or throw an exception outside of the switch.

Comment: I'm confused and don't understand at all. Why should I be using && instead of ||? In your head, how exactly do you read/interpet my while loop? How is it validating? What does the while loop do versus what I want it to do? @Tas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your while loop **always** returns true. You're using `||` when you should be using `&&`. Any input is either `not 1` or `not 2` or `not 3`.

Change your code to this and it'll resolve the problem.

```
do {
    cout << "Are you in section 1, 2, or 3?";
    cin >> response;
} while (response != 1 && response != 2 && response != 3);
```

As for the error you're getting, it might be the case that your `decisionThing` won't in real life get a number that's not `1`, `2` or `3` but compiler doesn't know that. If that method gets a number that doesn't satisfy either of those cases, what should happen? it's not defined. Therefor we have a path for this code to not return anything in a function that's designated to return a string. You can return an empty string or throw an exception or handle the `default` case like this:

```
string decisionThing(int response)
{
    string date;

    switch (response)
    {
        case 1:
            date = "The test will be held on the 5th.\n";
            return date;
        case 2:
            date = "The test will be held on the 6th.\n";
            return date;
        case 3:
            date = "The test will be held on the 9th.\n";
            return date;
        default:
            date = "Wow, this is really unexpected, I guess nothing?\n";
            return date;
    }
}
```

By the way, you don't need the `break`s when you have `return`. The function will immediately return so anything after that simply won't get executed.

Comment: That will not fix the "not all control paths return a value" warning but it will fix that it keeps repeating.

Comment: You're right, I left a comment for him but I think I should edit my answer as well.

Comment: I'm confused and don't understand at all. Why should I be using && instead of ||? In your head, how exactly do you read/interpet my while loop? How is it validating? What does the while loop do versus what I want it to do?

Comment: `||` means or and `&&` means and: you want to accept only `1` or `2` or `3`. Okay as long as the final expression in the `while` evaluates to `true`, the loop will continue. If the value is either `1`, or `2` or `3` you want the expression to evaluate to `false` so you can get out of the loop. Okay, as long as response isn't 1 AND it's not 2 AND it's not three at the same time, then repeat the loop.

Comment: You can also define it using `||` but then you'll have to say something like this: `while (!(response == 1 || response == 2 || response == 3))`

Comment: I'm confused to what my while loop was trying to say versus what I thought it was doing? Could you explain it in more simple language, your response went over my head/was very confusing to me. Shouldn't || work since it has to be either 1 or 2 or 3, and if it's not equal (!=) then it keeps repeating. However when it's true it should stop repeating? Why doesn't it work here?? In what cases should I use && and ||?

Comment: Why does my while loop always return true instead of false? Why work && work isntead? Shouldn't && make it impossible to ever be false? Why does || make it always true, basically is what I'm asking?

Comment: To make it more simple, plug in actual values to response. If response is 1, your original expression `response != 1 || response != 2 || response != 3` evaluates to `1 != 1 || 1 != 2 || 1 != 3` which then evaluates to `false || true || true` which in English means, either false or true or true, which obviously is true. `true || false` is `true` and `true && false` is `false`. Okay, now do the same thing with `2` and `3`, do they return false ever?

Comment: So why would && work instead of ||? Could you provide another simple explanation similar to the one you used? I learn visually like this, thank you :))) Also are you saying because in all of these cases, if you put in 1 value (1 2 3), one of the 3 parts is true which makes the whole thing true so it keeps repeating?

Comment: Yeah that's right, just remind yourself this. `E1 & E2` evaluates to `true` only when `E1` and `E2` are both `true` and `E1 || E2` evaluates to `true` when either `E1` or `E2` is true. So when you want to stop looping when the value is either 1, 2 or 3 you should think of it this way. As long as (while) response is not 1 and it's not 2 and it's not three, repeat cause it's not valid. Or to make it slightly simpler, think of it in reverse, you want to stop the loop when response is 1 or 2 or 3, so when it's not true, you want to repeat. Ok, then negate it using `!`.

Comment: I mean just do literally what I did, in `response != 1 && response != 2 && response != 3`, plug in one of the values, like `2` for instance. `2 != 1 && 2 != 2 && 2 != 3` = `true && false && true` which evaluates to `false` which causes the loop to exit. anything else like `4` would make it true which makes it repeat.

Comment: also if this answers your question, don't forget to accept it answer please.